# What would be the minimum specifications needed for a Java Web server?

Tags: java, tomcat, vps

I rented a cheap linux VPS to try and learn how to build a java web application and ran into the problem of not enough memory to run the Java virtual machine let alone Tomcat.

This system is running Red Hat linux with something like 175 megs of ram (225 burstable but who cares about that). After LAMP got installed there isn't any ram left. Well, it says there's 50 megabytes free but I think that's the burstable stuff.

Even if it wasn't, is 50 megabytes enough ram to run the java virtual machine and tomcat and a hello world application? It doesn't sound like it would be enough.

Would anyone know how much ram, minimum, I would need for a project like this and if they have any suggestions of decent vps hosting companies I could rent from.

Thanks

Comment: Get a linode.com VPS - $20 a month for 512Mb of RAM.  That's plenty for Tomcat and a simple java web app.

Answer (score 1):

How about an Aws micro instance. Its free until you get over a usage quota. I have a personal blog with a few hundred hits a day and rarely go over quota. I think in total I have paid $3 this year even though my instance runs all the time. You would not even need that as you are just testing it out. Also you have ssh access so complete control of the device without the hassle of managing an actual box.

See [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) for info.

> As part of AWS’s Free Usage Tier, new AWS customers can get started
>   with Amazon EC2 for free. Upon sign-up, new AWS customers receive the
>   following EC2 services each month for one year:
>
> ```
> 750 hours of EC2 running Linux/Unix Micro instance usage
> 750 hours of EC2 running Microsoft Windows Server Micro instance usage
> 750 hours of Elastic Load Balancing plus 15 GB data processing
> 30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage (EBS) plus 2 million IOs and 1 GB snapshot storage
> 15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services
> 1 GB of Regional Data Transfer
> ```

Comment: This is a good idea. Also try out Heroku and Google App Engine.

Comment: Be advised that will cost you $30/month after the free year btw. At least last time I looked.

Comment: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html I calculated here it will be ~10-15 / month for my use case. App engine has a free tier with no year limitation so that might more useful although the APIs are somewhat different.